How to reliably route traffic for specific websites over different gateways in OPNsense?
I have specific websites I want going out through WAN_DHCP, and all other traffic going out through Mullvad_Wireguard. I can get it working unreliably, but if the host name does not resolve to the ip address saved in OPNsense it ends up getting sent over the VPN. I tried using the ASN, but everyone seems to be using the same two or three ASNs so the routing ends up being wrong. I can use GEOIP, which covers the majority of my use cases. However, I'd like to add a third gateway to try shadowsocks on websites that block VPNs to see if that let's me get around their block. Once I can get these three situations working I can solve all other variations.
To sum it up, I need four gateways total for all use cases. With GEOIP I can route to different VPNS in different countries by default. I then need to setup rules for exceptions for which websites traffic goes out over WAN_DHCP or through Shadowsocks. So, the order of the rules would be the exceptions first, followed by the default gateway depending on the VPN server to use for that site.
How can I properly route to the right gateway reliably?


Although I am not using Opensense, here is my take.
When you add a route to a router then you can also assign a metric to the connection.
The lower the metric value, the higher the priority.
You want your default route to be the Mullvad_Wireguard connection and let it have as high as possible metric, since it should only be matched if none of the other lines matches.
You can then add all the excempted ip addresses as separate route that has a lower metric tgan the default route.
If it is just a single ip address that has to be sent over the WAN_DHCP connection, then it can be written as belonging to a network of /32 in CIDR notation.
Use your ISPs gateway address as the next hop address.
Also:
Add the ip address of the Mullvad VPN server as a separate static route.
The reason being: How would your VPN client now where to forward encrypted traffic, if the ip address of the VPN server is also being encapsulated by the tunnel? ;-)
It is basically a chicken and egg situation.
By following this template you are basically saying this to the router:
If (target ip address is listed above)
then 
  use DHCP_WAN
else 
  use Mullvad_Wireguard.


This doesn't really answer the question. Apparently the OP is looking for a way to "split tunnel" based on the destination's domain instead of IP (probably because the destination host's IP changes from time to time and has been relying on DDNS). (Not that I am saying what he wants must be possible though.)

Ok that is more in the realm of not possible, since we are mixing 2 different levels in the OSI stack with each other. DNS exist in level 7, while VPN (and routing in general) is level 3.

Although he could make his own "DDNS" service and do DNS lookup of destination address as a cron job that then update outbound routing table based on the resolved ip address. However it has it own set of problems. Cached results being one of them.
